# getTetherableIfaces returns nothing

Tags: android, usb, tethering, android-5.1.1-lollipop

The objective is to enable USB tethering programmatically. For this I'm relying on reflection and `ConnectivityManager`.

- `getTetheredIfaces` returns the interface `rndis0` when tethering is enabled via the phone menu and nothing when disabled.
- `getTetherableUsbRegexs` returns two regexes—`rndis\d` and `usb\d`.
- `getTetherableIfaces` returns `wlan0` if WiFi is enabled, nothing otherwise.

I would expect `getTetherableIfaces` to return `rndis0` or `usb0` which I could use to enable USB tethering using the `tether` method. Any idea why this is not happening or on how to enable USB tethering in these conditions?

If I try forcing either interface into the `tether` method I get a `Tried to Tether an unknown iface :rndis0, ignoring` error.